# Is synchronisation needed in onSensorChanged(...)?

Tags: android, thread-safety, android-sensors

I got a SensorEventListener which does in the onSensorChanged() method something like the following:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e){
   values = e.values.clone();
   handleEvent(); //do some computations
}
```

Where values is a class variable which will be accessed in the handleEvent() method in order to do some computations. 
My question is now whether I have to lock the variable values, i.e. could values be overridden by another thread calling onSensorChanged() while some other thread is in handleEvent()?

thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnSensorChanged gets called inside the UI-Thread so if you  access `values` in another thread than the ui-thread you need to synchronize or use other techniques like a queues for example.

Comment: ok thanks for the quick answer. 

By the way, which thread is actually calling the `onSensorChanged()` method? Is this some system thread? 
Why wouldn't I need synchronisation if I would access `values` from the UI-thread?

Comment: i edited my answer. OnSensorChanged is called inside UI-Thread.

Comment: ah ok interesting! This implies then that `onSensorChanged()` will not be called by some thread while 1 thread is working in `onSensorChanged()` right? Since there is only 1 UI-thread, correct?

So for this case I wouldn't need a synchronization as the UI thread would then also execute my `handleEvent()` method...

Could I ask from where you know that the UI-thread calls `onSensorChanged()`?

Comment: The developer docs would clearly say so if it where otherwise. :-) Also i'm updating Views from inside onSensorChanged in my own App. That would lead to a crash if I were to do this from another thread than the UI-Thread.